# stream of output into a stream of variables

Tags: ksh

I have two queries that I am running against two different systems. They each return one row, and I want to output them on a single line.

if the queries produce results similar to:

```
echo this that and more
echo other great news
```

I want to be able to do some reordering and formatting like so:

```
echo other this that great news and more
```

If I could figure out how to echo the output of the line into multiple variables I would be good. I got this to work:

```
echo this that and more | while IFS=" ", read a b c
do
  echo a=$a b=$b c=$c
done
```

But once I am out of the while loop the variables a b and c are out of scope and no longer have their values.

Comment: First off, welcome!  For what it's worth, this worked fine for me under bash.

Comment: Is the comma after `IFS=" "` a typo, or in your actual code?

Comment: Well, if you want one row of data, why not pipe everything into `tr -d '\n' ` to delete the newline character or `tr '\n' ' '` to substitute with space ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that they *are out of scope*, `ksh` (at least the AT&T version) doesn't have that limitation of `bash`. It's that `read` is called twice.

The second time is the one where it fails and gets you out of the loop.

As that second `read` reads nothing, it sets a, b and c to the empty string.

Just do:

```
echo this that and more | IFS=" " read a b c
echo "a=$a b=$b c=$c"
```

Comment: Something was wrong with the way it worked, but I did get it to work. Here is my actual command: $> hive -f q1.hql | IFS=" " read var1 var2 ... var5<eol> I don't know why but it was breaking it up and putting a lot of the values in var1 and then none in var2,3,4 and then the rest in var5. I changed it to two commands $> line_x=$(hive -f q1.hql)<eol> $> echo line_x | IFS=" " read var1 var2 ... var5<eol> and this worked.

Comment: @markwusinich, possibly the fields were tab separated and you forgot the quotes in `echo $line_x` which would cause the sequences of $IFS characters to be converted to a single space (and globs expanded). If you just do `hive -f -q1.hql | read var1 var2...` without touching IFS, that would split on any sequence of tab and space (the default value of IFS has space tab and newline).

Answer (score 0):

```
a=$(echo this...)
b=$(echo other...)
echo -- "$a $b"
```